# UnitOfWork doesn't update all items based on a condition

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unit-of-work

I have this method:

```
public bool UpdateOfficeApprovers(IList<int> invoiceLinesToUpdate, int userId)
{   
    foreach (var invoiceLineId in invoiceLinesToUpdate)
    {
        var invoiceLine = _unitOfWork.InvoiceLineRepository.Get(invoiceLineId);

        invoiceLine.OfficeUserId = userId;

        if (!invoiceLine.HasTwoUniqueApprovers)
        {
            // do something here to avoid this line being updated
        }
    }

    _unitOfWork.Save();

    return hasUniqueApprovers;
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is go through all the invoiceLines and update their OfficeUserId. However there is the condition `HasTwoUniqueApprovers` and if this is `false` I don't want to update this invoiceLine but just leave it.

Ok so the line:

```
invoiceLine.OfficeUserId = userId;
```

Will update the entity state to `EntityState.Modified` correct?

So when:

```
 _unitOfWork.Save();
```

This will save all the invoiceLInes because it saves everything with:

```
EntityState.Modified
```

So what I'm wanting to know is how to stop certain invoiceLInes from being updated.

So when an invoiceLine meets the condition how do I set it so it won't be updated?

Comment: Check scopes and indents, you're have a mistake. I've edited somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Innstead of checking !HasTwoUniqueApprovers; just check whether the entity HasTwoUniqueApprovers then update this entity. The other entities which have "HasTwoUniqueApprovers" false will be in unchanged state and they will not be processed in the objectcontext.

```
public bool UpdateOfficeApprovers(IList<int> invoiceLinesToUpdate, int userId)

{   
    foreach (var invoiceLineId in invoiceLinesToUpdate)
    {
        var invoiceLine = _unitOfWork.InvoiceLineRepository.Get(invoiceLineId);


    if (invoiceLine.HasTwoUniqueApprovers)
    {
        invoiceLine.OfficeUserId = userId;
    }
}

_unitOfWork.Save();

return hasUniqueApprovers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either not set `OfficeUserId` for the line you don't want to save or set its state back to Unchanged.

```
objectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(invoiceLine, EntityState.Unchanged);
```

or in DbContext API:

```
dbContext.Entry(invoiceLine).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```